# Bootcamp Windows 10 internal speakers don't work, audio port lights red

Tags: bootcamp, audio, windows

I'm having problems with the audio in my Mid-2012 Macbook Pro running with Bootcamp Windows 10. There's no sound coming from the internal speakers, and the audio port lights red.

In OSX, I managed to fix this problem by holding a Volume key and disconnecting the headphone jack, and miraculously, it works!

The problem still remains in Bootcamp Windows 10. How can this problem be fixed?

I installed Windows 10 on my Macbook using Bootcamp Assistant on OSX.

Comment: Was Windows 10 installed using the Boot Camp Assistant or upgraded from Windows 7?

Comment: I installed it with Bootcamp Assistant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to solve this issue:

First in OSX, I installed the "Latest Windows support software from Apple" on a USB flash drive via **Utilities** -> **Boot Camp Assistant**.

Then in Windows, I reinstalled the missing audio driver using the `BootCamp.msi` installation file located in `WindowsSupport/BootCamp/Drivers/Apple` in said USB flash drive.

Internal speakers now work normally again, and the audio port no longer lights red!